# Motion in drilldown bubble chart Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have created a drilldown for bubble chart. data for this drilldown is like:

```
drilldown: {
        series: [{
            id: 'animals',
            data: [
                ['Cats', 5],
                ['Dogs', 2],
                ['Cows', 1],
                ['Sheep', 2],
                ['Pigs', 1]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'fruits',
            data: [
                ['Apples', 4],
                ['Oranges', 2]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'cars',
            data: [
                ['Toyota', 4],
                ['Opel', 2],
                ['Volkswagen', 2]
            ]
        }]
    }
```

can i use data in sequence for drilldown for eg: 
id:animals data will be so when i scroll horizontal datapoints for Cats will render one by one.

```
data: [
                ['Cats', [5,1,2,3,4]],
                ['Dogs', [2,1,5,6,7]]
            ]
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmc8fyd9/2/)

Comment: So you would like to get multiple series drilldown? You can see this SO topic in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38001100/highcharts-drilldown-and-combining-chart-type/38007444#38007444 And here you can find Highcharts forum topic connected with this issue: http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/drill-down-from-line-to-multiple-series-t35350/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Motion plugin currently does not support drilldown series, but it is quite possible to achieve.

Your JSFiddle is on the right path, but it needs a workaround for making Motion notice the changes in series when the chart drills down.

Working solution at JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/larsac07/Lon306y5/.

The drilldown series have to be prepared for Motion, and Motion has to be aware of changes in series:

```js
// Array that keeps track of prepared drilldown series.
var preparedDrilldowns = [];

// This function is called for each series, including drilldown
// series, and prepares it by setting an initial value for each
// point if the series is not already prepared.
function prepareDrilldowns(e) {
    var chart = e.target,
        motion = chart.motion,
        value;
    if (motion) {
        Highcharts.each(chart.series, function (series) {
            if (preparedDrilldowns.indexOf(series.name) < 0) {
                Highcharts.each(series.points, function (point) {
                    value = point.sequence[motion.round(motion.playRange.value)];
                    point.update(value, false, false);
                });
                preparedDrilldowns.push(series.name);
                series.chart.redraw();
            }
        });
    }
}

// This function updates Motion with the current series (when 
// drilldown is triggered, the current chart series are swapped).
function updateChart(e) {
    var motion = e.target.motion;
    if (motion) {
        motion.dataSeries = e.target.series;
    }
}
```

Call the functions via chart events:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        // Called for each redraw
        redraw: function (e) {
            // Call updateChart() for each redraw
            updateChart(e);

            // This is only called once per series and
            // drilldown series.
            prepareDrilldowns(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Drilldown charts are not meant to be used this way. They are meant to show categories and subcategories of data. You cannot drill down to subcategories and then compare one set of data to another.

Based on your sample data, I have two suggestions:

1. Start with the three main categories (animals, fruits, cars) and have them drill down into the subcategories (for example, "animals" drills down to cats, dogs, cows, sheep, pigs). You would have only one column for each category and subcategory (five cats, two dogs, etc.).
2. Start with two main categories (cats, dogs) and have them drill down into their subcategories (for example, "cats" drills down to the values `[5,1,2,3,4]`). You would need to have a reason to compare cats with dogs (maybe five short-haired, one long-haired, two mixed-breed, etc.).

Think about what kind of comparisons you want to explain to your readers and what will be the clearest and easiest way for them to understand those comparisons.

Comment: I am not comparing values here. I mean when there are multiple data points for same key. e.g. ['Cats', [5,1,2,3,4] .Cats have 5 values so when i scroll these values should be render one by one.

Comment: @RajuRajoriya OK. In that case, you would want a total number of cats that would drill down to the `[5,1,2,3,4]` values. Would a code example be helpful?

Comment: yes. sure.like charts in motion when playAxis moves datapoints changes same case applies here. when i scroll

Comment: This is the fiddle where i am doing the same thing : http://jsfiddle.net/Trinetra007/vmc8fyd9/2/

Comment: if you will click bubble 20 no drilldown bubble render, if you will click bubble 80 . Bubble drilldown will come.

Comment: @RajuRajoriya For others who will read this page, could you please update your question with the fiddle you posted here and the specific problem that you're trying to solve? That way, it's clearer for others who may have this problem and are looking for a solution. In the meantime, I'll look at your fiddle and see what I can solve for you.