# How to load data dynamically using JSON call in Highcharts Drill Down pie chart?

Tags: asp.net, json, highcharts, drilldown

I am working on a graph that I have to show as drill down with dynamic data. First I tried to load static drill down data and graph worked perfectly fine. But I need to load data dynamically, for that, I am using JSON calls to fetch data from Server with given "point name" (selected point of pie chart). When it loads the first time, it is working fine to show series data in a pie chart. But when I am clicking on pie chart objects, I receive a server call and gets data as JSON response but it's not updating pie chart.  Also, I need to keep navigation, so I can go forward or backwards at any point.

I am using below code but it is not working as multiple level pie chart, does anybody has done same, who can review below code and suggest how can I do this.

```
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chart_divDrillDownGraph',
                type: 'pie',
                events: {
                    drilldown: function (e) { 
                        if (!e.seriesOptions) {
                            if (!e.seriesOptions) {
                                $.get("http://localhost:54877/GetStats.aspx?key=drilldownGraph&selectedPointName=" + e.point.name, function (data) {
                                    this.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, data); 
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Report of March 2017'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Click the slices to view details.'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '{point.name}: {point.y:.1f}<span style="unicode-bidi: bidi-override;">%</span>'
                    }
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span><span style="unicode-bidi: bidi-override;">: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total</span><br/>'
            },
            series: [{}],

            drilldown: {
            }
        };

        if (this.name != "undefined" && this.name != null)
            selectedlevelName = this.name;
        else
            selectedlevelName = "";

        var url =  "http://localhost:54877/GetStats.aspx" + "?key=drilldownGraph&selectedPointName=" + selectedlevelName;
        $.getJSON(url,  function(data) {
            options.series[0].data = data; 
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
```

But I am getting below error

> TypeError: this.addSeriesAsDrilldown is not a function

I am using following JS of high charts
http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js
http://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In ajax request this keyword does not refer to the chart. You need to keep reference to the chart in ajax call.

```
events: {
                drilldown: function (e) {
                        if (!e.seriesOptions) {
                           var chart = this;

                            $.get("http://localhost:54877/GetStats.aspx?key=drilldownGraph&selectedPointName=" + e.point.name, function (data) {
                                chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, data); 
                            });
                        }
                }
            }
```

The rest options are correct - but your data should have the proper drilldown configuration - take a look at the answers from [Highcharts async multi level drill down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37890346/highcharts-async-multi-level-drill-down) how your data should look like.

Comment: thanks for your reply, after updating that statement this error is removed but still graph is not showing details when i click on any point, below is the output that I am getting in JSON response

{"series":[{"id":1,"name":"Dep1","y":45,"drilldown":"Dep1"},{"id":2,"name":"Dep2","y":25,"drilldown":"Dep2"},{"id":3,"name":"Dep3","y":10,"drilldown":"Dep3"},{"id":4,"name":"Dep4","y":5,"drilldown":"Dep4"},{"id":5,"name":"Dep5","y":15,"drilldown":"Dep5"}]}

Comment: it should be {"data": [ ... ]} instead of "series" - http://jsfiddle.net/h6pt9yap/